# Centring an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I'm new to JavaScript. As you can see below, a gif file displaying before redirection but the problem is that the loading.gif is displaying out of the upload-box div. How can I bring it inside the div and centre it(auto margin).

I tried many ways but I couldn't make it work!

Here is the JS function:

```
//Disabling autoDiscover
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
$(function() {

//Dropzone class
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone");
myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function() {

    // Display "Please Wait" gif
    var myImage = new Image();
    var ImgSrc = "./loading.gif";
    myImage.setAttribute("src", ImgSrc);
    myImage.style.margin = "0 auto";
    document.body.appendChild(myImage);

    // Wait 3 seconds and then redirect to the link
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    location.href = 'http://www.i-0s.ir/site';
    }, 3000);
});
});
```

And here is the HTML part:

```
<div class="upload-box">
    <p>Please upload your files</p>
    <div class="image_upload_div">
        <form action="upload.php" class="dropzone"></form>
    </div>
</dive>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    //Dropzone class
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone");
    myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function() {

        // Display "Please Wait" gif
        $('.upload-box').append('<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="./loading.gif"/></div>')

        // Wait 3 seconds and then redirect to the link
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            location.href = 'http://www.i-0s.ir/site';
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```